# AttributeError: can't set attribute from nltk.book import *

Tags: python, nltk, python-3.5

after installing nltk i import nltk and then use nltk.download() but when i try to use this "from nltk.book import *" it shows attribute error.
from nltk.corpus import * and from nltk import * works fine

i am new to natural language processing so i dont know much about this please help

from nltk.book import *
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***

Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9

Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.

Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

```
from nltk.book import *
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\book.py", line 
19, in

```
text1 = Text(gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt'))
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 295, in **init**

```
tokens = list(tokens)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-

packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 233, in **len**

```
for tok in self.iterate_from(self._toknum[-1]): pass
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 291, in iterate_from

```
tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py", line 117, in _read_word_block
    words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\regexp.py", line 126, in tokenize
    self._check_regexp()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\regexp.py", line 121, in _check_regexp
    self._regexp = compile_regexp_to_noncapturing(self._pattern, self._flags)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 56, in compile_regexp_to_noncapturing
    return sre_compile.compile(convert_regexp_to_noncapturing_parsed(sre_parse.parse(pattern)), flags=flags)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 52, in convert_regexp_to_noncapturing_parsed
    parsed_pattern.pattern.groups = 1

AttributeError: can't set attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you worked our your issue.
Just in case, same issue also reported here:
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1135

Solution:
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1106

"I was able to fix this problem by going into the `internals.py` file in the `nltk` directory and removing the line `parsed_pattern.pattern.groups = 1`. My rationale behind this was, after doing a bit of code reading, the [original version](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release22-maint/Lib/sre_parse.py) of `sre_parse.py` that NLTK was designed to work stored `groups` as an attribute of an instance of the `sre_parse.Pattern` class. The version that comes with Python 3.5 stores `groups` as a property which returns (I'm not too familiar with properties, but this is what I presume it does) the length of a `subpattern` list. [The code I'm talking about is here at about line 75.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/sre_parse.py) What I don't know is what the long term effects of doing this will be, I came up with this solution just by tracing through the code, I haven't looked at what bugs this may cause in the long run. Someone please tell me if this would cause problems and if there's a better solution."

The above works for me without any issues so far.